# PredicateBuilder "And" Method not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I have downloaded the [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and am having a difficult time getting it to work with the entity framework.  Here is my code: v_OrderDetail is the entity

```
var context = new OrdersEntities();

Expression<Func<v_OrderDetail,bool>> whereClause = w => true;                                         
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<v_OrderDetail>();              
predicate.And(w => w.Status == "Work");                             
var results = context.v_OrderDetail.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```

When I look at the results I get back every order.  The And predicate doesn't seem to take.  When I look at the predicate.parameters.count it only shows 1.  I'm not sure, but I would expect it to show 2 after I add the second one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because `predicate.And` doesn't modify `predicate`, it returns a new `Expression<Func<v_OrderDetail, bool>>` instead.  You need to assign the result somewhere so you can use it.

It will work if you do the following:

```
predicate = predicate.And(w => w.Status == "Work");
```

The problem here is that Expression trees are immutable.  Each time you modify an expression tree you must do so by creating a brand new one with the required change.

Here's a relevant excerpt from [How to modify expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) from MSDN.

> Expression trees are immutable, which means that they cannot be modified directly. To change an expression tree, you must create a copy of an existing expression tree and when you create the copy, make the required changes. You can use the [ExpressionVisitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) class to traverse an existing expression tree and to copy each node that it visits.